# How to decrypt SSHv2 using AES-256 session keys from memory dump?

Tags: linux, ssh, aes, decryption, memory

### How to decrypt the plaintext contents of an SSH session from a PCAP file and SSHv2 AES session keys from a memory dump.

I have the full PCAP for the SSH sessions, including the initial handshake and AES session keys from a memory dump of the process.

I also have the client's private keys.

Is it possible? If so, what tools can I use?

Thanks for any help.